# Apply color correction to multiple images with Photoshop

Tags: automation, photoshop

I edited an image in Photoshop (color, brightness and some other things).
Now I want to do apply the same changes to some other images.
How can I automate this process?

Comment: This question fits to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: there is some programs, i.e. free ImBatch  -
 http://www.highmotionsoftware.com/products/imbatch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to record an action. Go to `Window > Actions`. There's a button similar to "**new layer**" in that Action Window. That action will record everything that you are doing in Photoshop.

After you are done you can batch apply that action using Photoshop's Batch. Go to `File > Automate > Batch ...` In that windows at the top you  will find "**play**" section where you can select which action do you want to apply. After that you select the Source(Folder) and the destination of where you want to save the files after the action has been applied.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Amazing answer! it saved me hours..thank you Dorin :)